# How to populate a form with data selected from options on my mysql data

Tags: php, mysql

I have  a form data selects data from the database. I want each selected item to have their units echoed in the corresponding unit input form. pls I need a simplified way of solving this problem. 
Here is the form:

```
<?php include ("header.php");?>

<?php

$start=1;
$end= $_POST['item'];

for($start;$start<=$end;$start++){

require("connect.php");

$sql = "(SELECT * FROM drug_name)";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
?>

<form align="center" method="post" action="transactions.php" id='myform'>
        Name:
        <select align="right" name="inputname[]" id='Drug_item_Name'
 value="Drug_Item_Name"><option selected="selected" value="0">S/N Select drug --</option>
<?php while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){ ?>
        <option ><?php echo$row['Drug_Item_Name']?></option>    
        <?php
}
    ?>
        </select>
        <td  align="right">Unit:</td>

        <td><input type="text" name="input2[]" 
        placeholder="Enter UNIT"   size="7" ></td>

        <td  align="right">QTY:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="input3[]" placeholder="Enter QTY" size="5"></td>
        </tr> 

<?php       echo '<br>'; ?>

<?php }

?>

<td><INPUT TYPE="submit" NAME=Dispense" SIZE="10"  value="Dispense"></td></table></form>

        </form>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Populating an input field from selected data on a dropdown list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31355253/populating-an-input-field-from-selected-data-on-a-dropdown-list)

Comment: Also duplicates [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31369525/autopopulating-a-dynamically-generated-form), which is probably the best of the three duplicates.