# Autopopulating a dynamically generated form

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I built a form that can select data from MySQL database and the desired field of the selected row will be displayed in an input field of a form. However, this form is dynamic in the sense that you can have multiple forms of the same form.

If two or more forms are generated, only the first form is auto populated. I want each form to auto-populate their corresponding input field upon selection of a row from the database.

[image: Illustration of forms]

Here is the code:

```
<?php
$start=1;
$end= $_POST['item']; echo'<br>';

for($start;$start<=$end;$start++){

require("connect.php");

$sql = "(SELECT * FROM drug_name)";


 $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);


?>
<form align="center" method="post" action="transaction.php">


        Name:
        <select align="right" name="inputname[]" onchange="showunit(this.value); showqty(this.value)"
 value="inputvalue[]">
 <option selected="selected" value="0">S/N Select drug --</option>

 <?php while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){ ?>

 <option value='<?php echo $row['SN']; ?>'><?php     

echo$row['Drug_Item_Name']?></option> 

        <?php
}
    ?>      

        </select>



        <td  align="right">Stock Level:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="input3[]" placeholder="Enter QTY" size="5" id="displayqty"></td>
        </tr> 


<?php       echo '<br>'; ?>

<?php }

?>   </form>
```

This is the code to make the AJAX code:

```
     <script>
        function showqty(str) {   

            if (str == "") {
        document.getElementById("displayqty").value = "";    
                return;  `
            } else {     
                if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {




                    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                } else {    
                    // code for IE6, IE5
                    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                        document.getElementById("displayqty").value = xmlhttp.responseText;
                    }
                }
                xmlhttp.open("GET","qtydisplay.php?q2="+str,true);
                xmlhttp.send();
            }
        }  


        </script>
```

This is the AJAX  code to fetch data from MySQL database:

```
        <?php

        $q2 = intval($_GET['q2']);
        include("connect.php");//connection to database


        mysqli_select_db($conn,"ajax_demo");
        $sql="SELECT Qty_Stocked FROM drug_name WHERE SN = '".$q2."' LIMIT 1";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);


        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array( $result)) {
            echo $row['Qty_Stocked'];  
        }

        mysqli_close($conn);
        ?>
```

Comment: The SQL is wrong for a start - remove the round brackets from inside the string. Other than that, I can't see a specific question. What in this script specifically is not working?

Comment: The `for()` loop is rather odd - you have given it a start value outside of the loop. Move this inside, thus: `for($start = 1; ...`.

Comment: @Halfer, thanks for the response. Only the first form auto-populates the input field. I want each form containing the <select><option></option></select> tag to be able to select data from the database and auto-populate their correspnding input field

Comment: Do you want to do that via AJAX? If so, do you have any code to attempt to do that already? If so, may we see it?

Comment: I have now re-edited your question to draw attention to the separate parts. I wonder if you need an image to show how the forms are meant to operate at present? It is good to have the code shown, but I don't think it is clear what the forms do, or what the AJAX replies should contain. It looks like you are returning integer values, do you just want to do that in all forms?

Comment: Yes I am returning integer values. The form has two columns, the first column has <select> and <potion> tag to select items from the database. The second column receives the field of the selected row (e.g If item A is selected, the price of item A from the database is shown on the input field). So I want each form to be able to that.If more than one form is generated, only the first one does it. I hope you now understand my question.

Comment: @Halfer, the system said I can't upload images b/c I have not gotten up to ten reputation.

Comment: Does that contain two forms? One for each menu-input pair?

Comment: The number of forms is user dependent. That is why I used the for() loop in my codes above. If the user wants say 5 items, 5 will be entered in a form. The action script is the script above. So each form contains two columns of the same kind- one for the drop-down option, fetching data from the database and the second column is auto-populated with a field data from the database upon selection. My challenge is that no matter the number forms generated, only the first form auto-populates.

Comment: It rather sounds like you are demanding an answer! Please be aware that volunteers answer at their leisure here.

Comment: It seems to be that `showqty(str)` is not notified of which quantity box to put the answer in. I think you need to pass an `id` to this function, and then change the `id="displayqty"` in the input tag to `displayqty1`, `displayqty2`, etc. It is not allowed to have duplicate ids anyway.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. But is there any JS array that can serve the purpose of multiple IDs?

Comment: You might be able to use `getElementsByTagName()`, which will return an array of elements. But to be honest, the way I suggested would be the way I'd do it.

Comment: sorry, I do not understand the way you said you would have done it. Can you please explain.

Comment: What don't you understand? Look it up in [the JavaScript docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName) and see how it works. You can do `document.getElementsByTagName('input')` to get an array of input tags, but if you have other input boxes on your page it will be a pain. Change your input `id` values as I've described (you have to do this anyway to avoid invalid HTML) and then pass an id name to each handler.

Comment: @Halfer, I tried using the the document.getElementsByTagName('input') but its not working.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I'd resolve this. I've given all this information in comments already, but perhaps it will help if I list it in a numbered fashion, so that it is unambiguous. It is probably best to avoid skipping items here, since each task relies on the previous one.

1. The first task is to fix your duplicate `id` attributes. Consider this HTML inside your loop:

   ```
   <td>
       <input type="text" name="input3[]"
              placeholder="Enter QTY" size="5" id="displayqty">
   </td>
   ```

   That will give you multiple input tags with conflicting unique identifiers. You could use an integer here, or would `$row['SN']` do it? If that value is unique, you could do something like this:

   ```
   <td>
       <input type="text" name="input3[]"
              placeholder="Enter QTY" size="5"
              id="displayqty_<?php echo (int) $row['SN'] ?>"
       >
   </td>
   ```

   (I have forced it to an int for security reasons, but if it is defined as an integer in the database, you don't need this).

   Once you have modified your code to render unique names for your id attributes, view your generated HTML and make sure it works.
2. You then need to modify your JavaScript function so that you can tell it what `id` to use. Since it is hardwired presently to `displayqty` it will only modify one element at most, which is not what you want. Try switching this:

   ```
   function showqty(str)
   ```

   to this:

   ```
   function showqty(str, id)
   ```

   You can then use the variable `id` instead of `"displayqty"` in your function.
3. Finally to wire it all together, your change handler needs to pass in the target `id`. Change this:

   ```
   showqty(this.value)
   ```

   to whatever string you used for `id` before. For example, maybe this?

   ```
   showqty(this.value, "displayqty_<?php echo (int) $row['SN'] ?>")
   ```

Bear in mind that this is not tested, and I only have a passing idea of what your screen is doing here. Do not expect this to work without a little bit of tweaking and debugging your end - if you are willing to persist, you will get there. Good luck!

Comment: thank you for taking your time to help. I really appreciate. But unfortunately I could not get. I tried all possible means but no avail. could you pls try it on your pc using an assumed database. Thanks.

Comment: I expect I could get it working @walex, but we try to encourage posters here to fix it for themselves - if someone does it for you then you'll not learn anything. What particular problem are you having? Do you have any JavaScript errors in your console?

Comment: I actually followed the steps you outlined above. I don't know if there should be a change in the JS script.

Comment: @walex: yes, I've changed the JavaScript.

Comment: Is the change in the above scripts?

Comment: Yes @walex, my post details amendments to your above scripts. The first change is to your first PHP file, the second one is to your JS file, and the third is a change to your PHP file again (although this is technically inline JS).

Comment: Do I need  to select the database at the JS portion so that "displayqty_<?php echo (int) $row['SN'] ?>" can be echoed? I think ordinarily inserting the code in between document.getElementById() will not select any id since there was no query on the database. pls what's your take?

Comment: I don't understand your question @walex: you cannot select a server-side database in JavaScript. The only relevant detail I can think of is that in this `for()` loop you should always have a `$row['SN']`, so I am not sure how you could encounter a situation where no ID is selected.

Comment: (It is possible I do not understand your use case. If it is possible to get a `displayqty` input tag which is not related to a database row, you will need to explain how that can happen, and whether you can have more than one of these not connected to a row. This way I might be able to understand what you are trying to accomplish).